# Email control in .NET environment

Tags: .net, open-source, mail-server

I am using .NET and I wonder if there is some free program (or .NET open source) that can help to queue and control email outflow:

1. Every time an email supposed to be sent, put it in the queue (database)
2. Queue database will have these information: Timestamp, Email Address, Time in Queue, Time Sent, Success, Number of Retry
3. Email must be in queue for AT LEAST x min before being sent
4. Email job is executed by batch of x number of email. Each job is delayed by x second interval

Something similar to the above would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like the SMTP adapter in Microsoft BizTalk Server. BizTalk is not free though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/rchartier/archive/2004/07/29/201055.aspx) is a blog article about that.  Most .NET SMTP controls will only handle the sending/receiving, you have to handle the queueing yourself.